# variable as python array key but without initialized or declared

Tags: python, arrays, function, command-line-arguments

**About**

in a python code which i seen in this site

https://amaral.northwestern.edu/blog/function-wrapper-and-python-decorator

**The code**

```
def my_add(m1, p1=0):
  output_dict = {}
  output_dict['r1'] = m1+p1
  return output_dic

def my_deduct(m1, p1=0):
  output_dict = {}
  output_dict['r1'] = m1-p1
  return output_dic
```

**My doubt is** , the code

```
output_dict['r1'] = m1+p1
```

represents that m1+p1 is stored in output_dict variable array in r1 th key. but "r1" is neither initialized nor even declared before used as a key. wont python throw a error ? .

if r1 is a variable , is it static or has a scope in the program?

Answer (score 1):

No, python would not throw an error ,rather then this it would automatically create a key in output_dict with value assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

`'r1'` is just a string, no need to initialize or declare it.

And `output_dict['r1'] = m1 + p1` means:

```
if 'r1' in output_dict:
    # change output_dict['r1'] to m1 + p1
else:
    # create a 'r1' key in output_dict, 
    # and assign value `m1 + p1` to it
```

Comment: `'r1'` is not a "temporary variable". It's not a variable at all. It's a string literal.

Comment: is it a static variable , i mean , is it confined to a particular scope?

Answer (score 0):

`"r1"` is just a string literal, like `"hello"` or `"hi"`, and what `output_dict['r1'] = m1+p1` is doing is that it is creating a key `r1` in `output_dict`, and then assigning `m1+p1` to it, all in one expression

A simpler example might be

```
In [42]: dct = {}                                                                                                              

In [43]: dct['a']='b'                                                                                                          

In [44]: dct                                                                                                                   
Out[44]: {'a': 'b'}

In [45]: dct['c']='d'                                                                                                          

In [46]: dct                                                                                                                   
Out[46]: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Here you see that after instantiating `dct` dictionary, I assigned a key and value pair `a,b` and then `c,d`